# Low Seg2Cat not working (empty output)

Tags: low-seg2cat, low

Hi Low (or anybody else),

I have a similar problem to [this one](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/low-seg2cat/viewthread/4851) in the old devot-ee-support-forums. When I use Seg2Cat-tags they produce nothing (means: empty output). Template-Debugging returns a lot of pipes in the Snippet-Values ("||||").

In the mentioned thread Low wrote:

> First of all, check if the correct category groups are selected in the extension settings. If the category in the URI belongs to a non-selected category group, then the empty string is correct output.

The category group is selected, the category exists.

> Or else, enable the output profiler and look up the SQL query performed by Seg2Cat, which should look something like “SELECT LOWER(cat_url_title) AS cat_url_title…”. Then run that query in the SQL manager. If there are results in the SQL manager, but not from the extension itself, then there’s a conflicting extension somewhere, probably. Check which extension use the sessions_end hook as well and try to disable them to see of that helps.

Now I used the SQL-query, I think it's this one:

```
SELECT `cat_url_title`, `cat_id`, `parent_id`, `group_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_description`, `cat_image`
FROM (`exp_categories`)
WHERE `site_id` =  '1'
AND `cat_url_title` IN ('schule', 'lowseg2cattesttrash', 'deutschunterricht') 
AND `group_id` IN ('1')
```

and I get one result (the correct category).

Now my question is if there is any help for me identifying the problematic plugin. I have a lot of plugins installed, mostly commercials which I need (Assets, CE Tweet, FireMail, LowSearch, Rating, Playa, Threaded Comments, Wygwam ...).

I would appreciate any help very much, because it would be a useful delight for me to use Seg2Cat.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of EE are you using? To check out which extensions use the sessions_end hook, fire this query: `SELECT * FROM exp_extensions WHERE hook = 'sessions_end';` You can then try to disable them one by one to find which one is causing the confict.

Comment: Hi Low, thanks for the answer. I am using as dev-system 2.7.2, but on my main-install with 2.8.1 I have the same problem. The query you told me to try returns just one extension: Seg2Cat. Do you perhaps have any other idea?

Comment: Send superadmin login credentials to hi at gotolow dot com, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Seg2Cat currently (v2.8.0) expects lowercase category url titles. If you have any uppercase characters in them, they will not be matched. By default, this should pose no problem, as EE will always lowercase them. But if you're importing them, or manually setting them, they might have uppercase letters in them.

To change all category url titles to lowercase, use this query:

```
UPDATE exp_categories SET cat_url_title = LOWER(cat_url_title);
```

This query will fix the issue in this case.

Comment: Thank you for publishing the SQL-code here - I already wanted to ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

Low himself was 2 minutes on my server and got it all fixed.
The problem was that the category url titles have been containing uppercase-letters. After converting everything to lowercase it all works.

A big thanks to Low for his quick and ultra-competent support!!